# How to specify font style in TextView

Tags: android

I want to implement different font in different TextViews.

I am trying to implement `fonts` from `assets` with this.

```
tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getContext().getAssets(), "Roboto.ttf");
bellow_name.setTypeface(tf);
```

But I have `TextView` something like this

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.news_date)).setText(news.news_date);
```

How can I implement `Typeface` with above `TextView`?

Comment: OLD question. Before asking question please search on GOOGLE

Comment: Please check my answer .

Answer (score 0):

**1.create a new fonts directory in the assets directory and put the Roboto.ttf font file here.**

You can change to this .

```
tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto.ttf");
bellow_name.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a object of `TextView` set type face with that

```
TextView bellow_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.news_date);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getContext().getAssets(), "Roboto.ttf");
bellow_name.setTypeface(tf);
bellow_name.setText(news.news_date);
```

If you have sub folder in Asset folder you have to add that. suppose...

```
assets(directory)
   -fonts(directory)
      -Roboto.ttf
      -Comics.ttf
```

Then change path like this

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(v.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto.ttf");
```